# powerbuilder: pfc_save problem

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc

I have a user object which is using pfc services. Now, during update, I have written my validation code in the `pfc_validation()` function, and when validation does not succeed, I am returning `-3` from that function. But still I am getting an error message saying - "A database error has occured.....", which means the update process is not aborting. I thought if I return `-3` from the `pfc_validation` function, it will stop the further update process.

Now how can I cancel the rest of the `pfc_save` process if validation fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your datawindow inherits from pfc_u_dw, you will see there (in the ancestor's pfc_validation event) that:

```
-1 = validation failed
```

Make sure that you return the value that is defined as the failure value in the ancestor

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how can I make sure that a text field in datawindow is not empty?

Comment: That can't be answered in a comment. You should try to read that field in the pfc_updateprep event, and act accordingly.